# How do I write a query to compare the indexes on two SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have to write a SQL script to compare the differences between the indices of two tables on SQL Server.  How can I get the structure of the indices on a table through a SQL query?

Comment: I don't understand - you want to find which different indices you have in a SQL Server database? Or what data is different?? You need to be more precise in asking....

Comment: What I understand is you want to compare two tables from different SQL server or Databases?

Comment: Go ahead and pop for SO's sponsor product (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). ***SQL Compare*** (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_bundles/SQL_Comparison_Bundle.htm) really will save money and time, for these kinds of tasks.

Comment: Basically I am working on a data migration project for an ERP application. The application version's are different therefore I have to examine the difference with index structure before migrating the data.

Comment: I dont want to buy a sql compare product.

Comment: let me rephrase the information how can i get the structure of the indices of table through sql query

Comment: @Huzaifa - Although SQL compare isn't that expensive it's fairly straightforward to get this information from the system data dictionary.  See my answer for an example of a script that does this.

Comment: @Huzaifa - Red Gate's tools are available with fully functional 14-day trials. Give them a go and if you still don't feel like you want to make a purchase after 14 days, you won't be any worse off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two databases are on the same server then you can do a series of queries that outer joins the sys.indexes and sys.index_columns tables on both databases.  You will also need to look at sys.index_columns to check that the columns are the same (also check for the same order - this will affect query plans).

If both databases are on different servers you will need to copy the contents of sys.indexes and sys.index_columns onto the other server and do a similar query against your copies of the tables.

An example of such a query might look like (substitute appropriate databases for FOO and BAR and add appropriate filters to the individual queries if you want to look at individual tables):

```
select *
  from
       (select s1.name           as SchemaName
              ,t1.name           as TableName
              ,c1.name           as ColumnName
              ,i1.name           as IndexName
              ,i1.index_id
              ,c1.column_id
              ,c1.system_type_id
              ,c1.user_type_id
              ,ty1.name          as ColumnType
              ,c1.collation_name  -- Note this is nullable
              ,c1.is_nullable
              ,c1.max_length
              ,c1.[precision]
              ,c1.scale
              ,ic1.index_column_id
              ,ic1.key_ordinal
              ,ic1.partition_ordinal
              ,ic1.is_descending_key
              ,ic1.is_included_column
          from [FOO].sys.schemas s1
          join [FOO].sys.tables t1
            on t1.schema_id = s1.schema_id
          join [FOO].sys.columns c1
            on t1.object_id = c1.object_id
          join [FOO].sys.types ty1
            on ty1.system_type_id = c1.system_type_id
           and ty1.user_type_id = c1.user_type_id
          join [FOO].sys.index_columns ic1
            on ic1.object_id = c1.object_id
           and ic1.column_id = c1.column_id
          join [FOO].sys.indexes i1
            on i1.object_id = ic1.object_id
           and i1.index_id = ic1.index_id) r1
  full outer join
       (select s1.name           as SchemaName
              ,t1.name           as TableName
              ,c1.name           as ColumnName
              ,i1.name           as IndexName
              ,i1.index_id
              ,c1.column_id
              ,c1.system_type_id
              ,c1.user_type_id
              ,ty1.name          as ColumnType
              ,c1.collation_name  -- Note this is nullable
              ,c1.is_nullable
              ,c1.max_length
              ,c1.[precision]
              ,c1.scale
              ,ic1.index_column_id
              ,ic1.key_ordinal
              ,ic1.partition_ordinal
              ,ic1.is_descending_key
              ,ic1.is_included_column
          from [BAR].sys.schemas s1
          join [BAR].sys.tables t1
            on t1.schema_id = s1.schema_id
          join [BAR].sys.columns c1
            on t1.object_id = c1.object_id
          join [BAR].sys.types ty1
            on ty1.system_type_id = c1.system_type_id
           and ty1.user_type_id = c1.user_type_id
          join [BAR].sys.index_columns ic1
            on ic1.object_id = c1.object_id
           and ic1.column_id = c1.column_id
          join [BAR].sys.indexes i1
            on i1.object_id = ic1.object_id
           and i1.index_id = ic1.index_id) r2 
    on r1.SchemaName = r2.SchemaName
   and r1.TableName = r2.TableName
   and r1.ColumnName = r2.ColumnName
   and r1.IndexName = r2.IndexName
```

Answer (score 1):

sys.indexes holds all the information about the indexes on a given database.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is the structure you can generate the scripts using this [procedure](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/).

You can then compare the files between the two databases.